# why my timestamp field become time map after embedding data into a list of map?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try to embed some event documents into a field in user document called `upcomingEvents` (list of map).

so first, I query event documents that will be embedded in user document like this

```
const willStartSoonEventsSnapshot = await db.collection('events')
        .where("createdBy","==", event.createdBy)
        .where("isActive","==", true)
        .where("hasBeenApproved","==", true)
        .where("dateTimeStart",">",now)
        .limit(7)
        .orderBy("dateTimeStart","asc")
        .get()
```

and then I update `upcomingEvents` field in user document using the code below

```
        const upcomingEvents = []

        willStartSoonEventsSnapshot.forEach( doc => {
            upcomingEvents.push(doc.data())
        })

        // trying to log createdAt field
        console.log(upcomingEvents[0].createdAt)


        db.doc(`users/${event.createdBy}`).update({
            upcomingEvents
        })
```

as you can see from the image below, initially in `events` collection, `createdAt` field is in timestamp data type

[image]

but after I run the code above and the data has successfully embedded in user document in `upcomingEvents` field (list of map), the time createdAt will be in map not in timestamp anymore like this

[image]

as you can see from the code above, I try to log the createdAt timestamp, and here is the result. there is data is in timestamp data type
[image]

I am using firebase cloud function to run the code above

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
```

so, why my timestamp field become map like that ? can I keep it in timestamp data type ?

Comment: What exactly is the data coming from the query? How do you know what the timestamp is actually supposed to be? You will need to do some debugging and show us specifically what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

From the data you have provided, it seems that the property of the date field is lost. Check in the code if the data is being stringified and parsed back.
Because if there is a date field in the record and you print it, you will see that it is something like this.

> {dateField: { nanoseconds:5651654613, seconds:21356883213 }}

That is the date received in the query result from firestore. And if the properties are lost then firestore will not consider this as a date object.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced it like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

main =  async function () {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const col_timestamp = await db.collection("col_timestamp").get();

    const  array = [];

    col_timestamp.forEach(doc => {
        array.push(doc.data())
    })

    db.doc("col_timestamp/copy/test_collection/timestamp_copy").update({array});
}
main();
```

And as result I have the timestamp like this:
[image]

I think I have reproduced all operation you have posted here so, there must have been some additional operations before `update` that changed properties.

I hope this will help!